# Getting General error: 4004 General SQL Server error:

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, laravel-5

I am trying to fetch data from my database in Laravel, however I am getting a "General error: 4004 General SQL Server error:"

I'm using Laravel-5 with MSSQL.
If I use the DB object to fetch data from MSSQL I am not able to fetch xml and nvarchar fields,

I found a usefull link below, but to implement this I have to rewrite all my queries. Is there any other way?

https://gullele.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/accessing-xml-column-of-sql-server-from-php-pdo

Comment: Error message : 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4004 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [4004] (severity 16) [(null)] (SQL: select top 1 * from [forms] where [id] = 1)

Comment: Add the error message to your question using the `edit` link under the `tags`. You should also provide your code and table's structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try :

```
 $handle = getHandle();
 $handle->exec('SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON');
 $handle->exec('SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON');
 $handle->exec('SET ANSI_PADDING ON');
 $handle->exec('SET ANSI_NULLS ON');
 $handle->exec('SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON');
```

OR

You can also check the server configuration:
check the "/etc/freetds.conf " file and change the tds version and add client charset then in php.ini please check mssql.charset and default_charset

in /etc/freetds.conf :

```
;tds version = 4.2
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

In php.ini :

```
mssql.charset = "UTF-8"
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

Comment: `tds version = 8.0` is not a valid tds version.  Please use auto.

Comment: @AlexBarker It is valid but should be avoided, since it is a very old version and might cause version conflict in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The most important information for everybody else is the answer to the question: **What does the error 4004 (severity 16) mean?**

> *Error 4004:* Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.

([Source](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-4001-5000.aspx))

In my case, I had to cast a `STUFF()` clause to `VARCHAR(MAX)` to resolve the error, after migrating to SQL Server 2016 and setting `tds version = 7.4`.