# Getting 4004 SQL Server error after execution of stored procedure with JSON input using PHP code

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

We created a stored procedure in SQL server which takes input parameter as JSON. Procedure is giving us results in JSON in the studio management. But, it is giving 4004 SQL server error after executing the procedure using PHP code. We are using pdo_mssql driver.

We did not get any sample code in PHP which passes input parameter as JSON. I got below link but no luck.

[Getting General error: 4004 General SQL Server error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428649/getting-general-error-4004-general-sql-server-error)

```
$stored_proc_stmt = "exec SP_NAME ? ";

$pdo_stmt = $this->_db->prepare($stored_proc_stmt);

$input = '{"productCode":"ABCD"}';

$pdo_stmt->bindParam(1, $input);

$stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SET ANSI_NULLS ON");
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SET  ANSI_WARNINGS ON");
$stmt->execute();

$pdo_stmt->execute();

$results = $pdo_stmt->fetchAll();
```

Expected result should be in JSON. We don't want to make any change at the configuration level in the DB.

Comment: Do other data access work?

Comment: @bradbury9 the user, which we are using have access to this stored procedure.

Comment: @user3744825  What driver do you use to connect to SQL Server? And I suppose, that your input parameter in stored procedure is `nvarchar(max)`, but how do you output JSON - as an output `nvarchar(max)` parameter or as a resultset? Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov  We are using Zend 1 framework and yes input parameter is nvarchar(max) and output is "returns integer". Is this return type issue?

Comment: @user3744825 The result of execution of stored procedure is always integer. If you use `$pdo_stmt->fetchAll();` then your stored procedure returns resultset - maybe as result from `SELECT  * FROM OPENJSON(...)` or `SELECT @InputParameter` AS JSONResult for example. About the driver - `pdo_mssql`, `pdo_sqlsrv` or `pdo_odbc`?

Comment: @Zhorov we are using pdo_mssql driver.